# Request for solution on sending integers to a text field

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am trying to write code that reads data from an excel file. The excel file has 7 columns and the first 5 columns consists of string type data and the last 2 columns consists of integer type data. Now I want to send this data to a form of a web page.

**Problem with my code:** My code is returning the entire excel data as strings where as I need only the first 5 columns as strings and the last 2 columns as integers. Also, though all the fields of a form of webpage are text fields, I am not sure why the fields are throwing an error " Invalid format" when I sent the string data. Could you please look into the below code and help me in resolving this issue.

@Test
    public void SampleCustNumFormat() throws Exception {

```
    String vURL;
    String vEmail;
    String vPswd;
    String vCnfmPswd;
    int vCustAccNum;
    int vZipCode;
    long iWait;
    int Size;
    // Read Test Data from Excel

    String xlPath = "C:\\SCE docs\\Automation\\InputData_Registration.xls";
    ArrayList<CustomerData> customerData = getExcelData(xlPath,"AccountHolderRegistration");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
      iWait=3000;

      for (int k=1; k<xRows; k++) 
      { 


                driver.navigate().to(vURL);
                driver.findElement(By.linkText("Register")).click(); 
                driver.findElement(By.id("emailInputBox_input")).clear(); 
                driver.findElement(By.id("emailInputBox_input")).sendKeys(vEmail); 
                driver.findElement(By.id("pwdInputBox_input")).clear(); 
                driver.findElement(By.id("pwdInputBox_input")).sendKeys(vPswd); 
                driver.findElement(By.id("confirmpwd_input")).clear(); 
                driver.findElement(By.id("confirmpwd_input")).sendKeys(vCnfmPswd); 
                driver.findElement(By.id("radio1")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("accountInputBox_input")).sendKeys(Integer.toString(vCustAccNum));
                driver.findElement(By.id("accountInputBox_input")).clear(); 
                driver.findElement(By.id("zipcodeBox_input")).sendKeys(Integer.toString(vZipCode));
                driver.findElement(By.id("zipcodeBox_input")).clear(); 
                driver.findElement(By.id("terms3")).click(); 
         /*       driver.findElement(By.id("registerButton_label")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("continueButton_label")).click();
                Thread.sleep(iWait);
          */                        

      }




}

// Custom Methods


public ArrayList<CustomerData> getExcelData(String Path, String shtName)
        throws Exception {
    ArrayList<CustomerData> customerDataList = new ArrayList<CustomerData>();

    File myxl = new File(Path);
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(myxl);
    HSSFWorkbook myWB = new HSSFWorkbook(fi);
    HSSFSheet mySheet = myWB.getSheet(shtName);

    xRows = mySheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
    xCols = mySheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

    for (int i = 1; i < xRows; i++) {
        HSSFRow row = mySheet.getRow(i);

        CustomerData customerDetails = new CustomerData();
        customerDetails.setvURL(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
        customerDetails.setvEmail(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
        customerDetails.setvPswd(row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
        customerDetails.setvCnfmPswd(row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());          
        customerDetails.setvCustAccNum((int) row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue());
        customerDetails.setvZipCode((int) row.getCell(6).getNumericCellValue());
        customerDataList.add(customerDetails);
        System.out.println("row 2: "+row.getCell(3));
    //  row.getCell(2).setCellValue(convertFormatCustNo(customerDetails.getCustNo()));


    }
    return customerDataList;

}
```

Comment: You obviously haven't 'written the code'. You are complaining that all data is being returned as strings and you have a method explicitly named `cellToString()`. What do you think that method does? The method `getExcelData()` returns a `String[][]` array, how do you expect it to return something else? Obviously you didn't write any of this and you're expecting us to give you the code without even trying to do anything yourself. And the output is not even of that code. There is nowhere in the code any line which outputs `Some Data`

Comment: I am not complaining, I know what is the output i am receiving and i want to know how to convert the last two columns from strings to integers before inputting it the web page. I have already posted another question and they have requested me to post a new question thats the reason i have posted this question.

Comment: the above posted is my actual code which returns the string data and the extension for converting to integer i did not post because to have a clear understanding for the person who is suppose to answer my question. And regarding the output i have deleted the print statements.

Comment: So where is the line that is outputing `Some Data`?

Comment: I have updated the code, please check for outputting some data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to design your classes properly to reflect the data model you are dealing with, rather than treating everything as String.

You can simply create a class that reflects one row in your excel sheet:

```
public class AccountHolder
{
  private String id;
  private String url;
  private String email;
  private String password;
  private String confirmPassword;
  private int accountNumber;
  private int zipCode;

  public AccountHolder() 
  {
  }

  public String getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }

  //todo: do the rest of the fields in the same way with public getters and setters

}
```

Then change `getExcelData()` to return an `AccountHolder[]` rather than just a bunch of `String` objects.

Finally modify `getExcelData()` in the loop:

```
AccountHolder[] accountHolders = new AccountHolder[xRows];

for (int i=0;i<xRows;i++) 
{ 
    HSSFRow row = mySheet.getRow(i); 

    AccountHolder accountHolder = new AccountHolder();
    accountHolder.setId(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

    //todo: the rest of the String fields of AccountHolder

    accountHolder.setAccountNumber(row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue());
    accountHolder.setZipCode(row.getCell(6).getNumericCellValue());

    accountHolders[i] = accountHolder;
}

return accountHolders;
```

That way you have an `AccountHolder` instance for each row, with each field having its proper type.

Comment: I have used the above approach by using arraylist but the code is asking me to initialize the variables that are defined in the code and  if do that my code is throwing null point exception. Could u please review the updated code.

Comment: Also, If i dont convert the CustomerNum and Zipcode to strings which are integers, the Sendkeys of selenium is not accepting. Hence i am not able to proceed further. Could u please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: You never mentioned Selenium anywhere in your question. Just change all fields to String and use that `cellToString()` method you had posted earlier.

Comment: hhhmmm... if do that i successfully able to send the data to fields of the form but after sending the data to the fields in form , the customernumber and zipcode fields throws an error message saying " INVALID FORMAT" though they are text fields. I am not able to find the reason behind this. Could u please guide me

Comment: From where is the INVALID FORMAT coming from? I have no idea what the rest of your applications looks like.

Comment: I have figured out after thorough validations and i could able to resolve the issue. Thanks a lot for the help. Really appreciate it.